# Xorg Conf: NVIDIA performance settings for AC/battery?

Tags: xorg, configuration, nvidia, gdm, thinkpad

I'm currently running Fedora on an old Thinkpad T530 and just configuring it to my needs. I'm using GDM/Gnome Desktop (on Xorg, not Wayland). I've installed and configured the proprietary NVIDIA driver.

Now I want to extend my battery's lifetime by forcing the driver running on lowest performance mode (current situation). That was my goal. But I want the adaptive mode back again on AC. I wasn't able to figure it out on my own and can't find any reference for NVIDIA's driver options.

My current `xorg.conf` contains:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option         "ConstrainCursor" "no"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1 PerfLevelSrc=0x2222; PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x3"
EndSection
```

I've found these options on [NVIDIA Developer Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/572053/linux/-solved-forcing-maximum-power-saving-on-the-desktop-quot-minimum-power-quot-mode-for-powermizer-/).
Can someone please help me (or pointing on any reference) so I'm able run both a) battery on lowest (forced) performance mode and b) an AC adaptive?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it! After searching the web again, I've found this [site on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/4djz3m/nvidia_users_to_help_with_screen_tearing_and_for/).

Basically the change is:

- `PerfLevelSrc` to `0x2233`, which means: fixed for battery (`22`) and dynamic for AC (`33`)
- `PowerMizerDefaultAC` to `0x2`, which means: set AC to dynamic/adaptive behaviour.

For clarification, setting `PowerMizerDefault` (same applies for `PowerMizerDefaultAC`) means:

- `PowerMizerDefault=0x1`: maximum performance
- `PowerMizerDefault=0x2`: dynamic performance
- `PowerMizerDefault=0x3`: minimum performance

My whole line is now:

```
Option         "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x2233; PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x2"
```

---

I'll just leave this here for others, seeking guidance.